# Prevent jQuery animate delays between queues on the same element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I have this code test:

```js
var rate = 50;
var x = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
  console.log("looped: " + i);
  $('#mydiv').animate({
    "left": x += rate
  }, 500);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px 0px;
}

#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv">Animate Test</div>
```

For loop animates the same element 15 times, all the 15 animate calls inside the loop are queued.

This animate function runs each queue at a time,

**The problem: There is a DELAY TIME ( maybe 500 ms i guess ) between each queue execution,**

You can run the snippet code and notice that delay.

*I want to make the element to move like it is not stopping for executing the next queue, just execute it immediately without that delay, like moving smoothly.*

i read a lot in the documentation about jQuery .animate()

i didn't see any mentions about this delay between queues,

any ideas or workarounds would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The default animation/easing of [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) is [`swing`](https://jqueryui.com/easing/).

If you change it to `linear` it goes without slowing down.

[image]

```js
var rate = 50;
var x = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
  console.log("looped: " + i);
  $('#mydiv').animate({
    "left": x += rate
  }, 500, "linear");
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px 0px;
}

#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv">Animate Test</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var rate = 50;
var x = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
  console.log("looped: " + i);
  $('#mydiv').animate({
    "left": x += rate
  }, 500,"linear");
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px 0px;
}

#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv">Animate Test</div>
```

Add `linear` after the speed and it should be smoother.